# Mac o Linker error(id) Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, admob

I was right about to build for my phone before I headed out and tested it while waiting in the car repair shop. The problem is that it started with a missing module. I thought there was a bug (turns out it wasn't), so I re-installed all ad packages (since I wasn't sure which one was causing the problem). I then came back into Xcode after building it again to come across 56 errors during the linking process of the app (after it compiles the scripts).

Here is just a cut version of the error

The Ad-providers I am using is Ad-mob and Unity Ads. I went through the error and looked it up.

```
"_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m892979392 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUShowRewardBasedVideoAd_m892979392)

  "_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady_m2978385106 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADURewardBasedVideoAdReady_m2978385106)

  "_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m4068511555 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetInterstitialCallbacks_m4068511555)

  "_GADUCreateInterstitial", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m2723672384 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateInterstitial_m2723672384)

  "_GADUSetRequestAgent", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m3592021267 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetRequestAgent_m3592021267)

  "_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m1408538185 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUTagForChildDirectedTreatment_m1408538185)

  "_GADUSetBirthday", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m4032274183 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUSetBirthday_m4032274183)

  "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys_m420572709 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdNumberOfAvailableAssetKeys_m420572709)

  "_GADUCreateRequest", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m3172610253 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUCreateRequest_m3172610253)

  "_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey_m1598890762 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUNativeCustomTemplateAdStringForKey_m1598890762)

  "_GADUAddTestDevice", referenced from:

      _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m3944259554 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_4.o

     (maybe you meant: _Externs_GADUAddTestDevice_m3944259554)
```

I thought I followed everything correctly, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by not installing cocoa pods. If you do have cocoa pods try reinstalling or updating it. Then reinstall the Google Mobile ads framework and reimport it into unity. That's what solved it for me....